# Memoria dinámica

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Hola tengo una duda respecto  a memoria dinámica en C.

Tengo la siguiente estructura :

```
struct flags  {

        unsigned  bit0:1; //1 bit de longitud
        unsigned  bit1:1;    
        unsigned  bit2:1;    
        unsigned  bit3:1;   
        unsigned  bit4:1;    
        unsigned  bit5:1;    
        unsigned  bit6:1;
        unsigned  bit7:1;
    };
    struct flags4 {

        unsigned  bit0:1; //1 bit de longitud
        unsigned  bit1:1;    
        unsigned  bit2:1;    
        unsigned  bit3:1;
    };
    typedef struct{
        uint8_t         tlv_type;
        struct flags    tlv_flags;
        uint8_t         tlv_type_ext;
        uint8_t         index_start;
        uint8_t         index_stop;
        uint8_t         length;
        uint8_t         value;  // para los tipo de ADDRESS TYPe
        uint8_t         *value_8bit; //Array  para la metrica
        uint16_t        *value_16bit;//Array para los numeros de secuencia
    }Pgman_tlv; 

    typedef struct{
        uint8_t      num_addr;              
        struct flags addr_flags;
        uint8_t      head_length;
        uint8_t      *head;
        uint8_t      tail_length;
        uint8_t      *tail;
        uint8_t      *mid;          
        uint8_t      *prefix_length;
        uint8_t      address_block_length;//no lo defiene el protocolo 
    }Pgman_address_block;

    typedef struct{
        uint16_t  tlvs_length;
        Pgman_tlv  *tlvs;
        uint8_t overall;
    }Pgman_tlv_block;

    typedef struct{
        uint8_t        msg_type;
        struct flags4  msg_flags;
        unsigned       msg_addr_length:4;
        uint16_t       msg_size;                
      //uint32_t       msg_orig_address;
        uint8_t        msg_hop_limit;           
      //uint8_t        msg_hop_count;    
      //uint16_t       msg_seq_num;       
        uint8_t        msg_header_length; //no lo defiene el protocolo
    }Pgman_msg_header;
    typedef struct 
    {
        Pgman_address_block  address_block;
        Pgman_tlv_block      tlv_block;

    }Pgman_Address_Tlv;

    typedef struct 
    {
        Pgman_Address_Tlv    *Address_Tlv;
        uint8_t              overall;
    }Pgman_Address_Tlv_list;
    typedef struct{
        Pgman_msg_header       msg_header;
        Pgman_tlv_block        message_tlv_block;       
        Pgman_Address_Tlv_list Address_Tlv_list;
    }Pgman_message;

    typedef struct{
        unsigned        version:4;
        struct flags4   pkt_flags;
      //uint16_t        pkt_seq_num;       
      //Pgman_tlv_block pkt_tlv_block;         
        uint8_t         pkt_header_length;  //no lo defiene el protocolo
    }Pgman_pkt_header;

    typedef struct{
        Pgman_pkt_header pkt_header;
        Pgman_message message;
        uint16_t packet_length; //no lo define el protocolo
    }Pgman_packet;
```

Los punteros apuntan a arrays asignando la memoria necesaria mediante malloc.
¿Cuando llega el momento de liberar la memoria tengo que ir puntero a puntero ejecutando FREE?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En efecto, no hay un método que resuma eso, pues tu eres el único que sabe en este lengua que memória reservaste con cada puntero que asu vez tienen nombres diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Si, la regla general es que por cada `malloc` (o `calloc`) debe haber un `free` correspondiente que libere esa memoria asignada, por lo que si me dices que a cada puntero son arreglos cuya memoria fue asignada por medio de `malloc` debes hacer un `free` correspondiente.

Te recomiendo que si usas ambiente linux para programar uses la herramienta valgrind que se encarga justamente de encontrar errores en el manejo de memoria.

Para buscar memory leaks y teniendo valgrind instalado podrias usar este comando: `valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./tu_programa`

Para darte un ejemplo sencillo hice este programa que asigna memoria dinamica correspondiente para tener un arreglo de 4 enteros en el puntero p.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int *p = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

  return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutar el comando que te dije anteriormente obtendremos este resultado.

```
==4115== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4115== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4115== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4115== Command: ./ejemplo
==4115==
--4115-- Valgrind options:
--4115--    --leak-check=full
--4115--    -v
--4115-- Contents of /proc/version:
--4115--   Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.i686 (mockbuild@c1bm.rdu2.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 201                                                                                            20313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Nov 18 18:48:28 UTC 2016
--4115-- Arch and hwcaps: X86, x86-mmxext-sse1-sse2
--4115-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--4115-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--4115-- Reading syms from /lib/ld-2.12.so
--4115-- Reading syms from /home/patricio/Documents/Projects/C/Knapsack Simple/ejemplo
--4115-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
--4115--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--4115-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--4115-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==4115== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-4115-by-patricio-on-vmcentos
==4115== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-4115-by-patricio-on-vmcentos
==4115== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-4115-by-patricio-on-vmcentos
==4115==
==4115== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==4115== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==4115== or are doing some strange experiment):
==4115==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=4115 ...command...
==4115==
==4115== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==4115==   /path/to/gdb ./ejemplo
==4115== and then give GDB the following command
==4115==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=4115
==4115== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==4115==
--4115-- REDIR: 0x4017d50 (strlen) redirected to 0x38048084 (vgPlain_x86_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--4115-- REDIR: 0x4017b30 (index) redirected to 0x3804805f (vgPlain_x86_linux_REDIR_FOR_index)
--4115-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-x86-linux.so
--4115-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so
--4115-- Reading syms from /lib/libc-2.12.so
--4115-- REDIR: 0x40b1f20 (rindex) redirected to 0x40281d0 (rindex)
--4115-- REDIR: 0x40ad240 (malloc) redirected to 0x402722c (malloc)
--4115-- REDIR: 0x40adec0 (free) redirected to 0x4026c29 (free)
==4115==
==4115== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4115==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==4115==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 16 bytes allocated
==4115==
==4115== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==4115== Checked 48,124 bytes
==4115==
==4115== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4115==    at 0x40272B2: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==4115==    by 0x80483D8: main (in /home/patricio/Documents/Projects/C/Knapsack Simple/ejemplo)
==4115==
==4115== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4115==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==4115==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4115==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4115==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4115==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4115==
==4115== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
--4115--
--4115-- used_suppression:     13 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
==4115==
==4115== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
```

El que nos aparezca lo siguiente:

```
==4115== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4115==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==4115==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 16 bytes allocated
```

Es signo claro de que hubo memory leak en nuestro programa, ya que en la salida del programa deberian haber 0 bytes en el HEAP, y ademas deberia haber la misma cantidad de frees que de allocs.

Si bien el sistema operativo de todas formas liberara esta memoria al momento de cerrar el programa imaginate que pasaria si estas ejecutando un programa el cual en un loop con muchisimas iteraciones pides memoria y nunca la liberas... podrias llegar a terminar usando toda tu memoria RAM disponible en tu programa, lo cual obviamente no quieres.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el consejo, lo pondré en práctica. También lo que había pensado , a ver qué os parece , un array de longitud igual al número de malloc, debido a que tendré que liberar la memoria asignada a dichos punteros al mismo tiempo, una vez la  estructura se serializa y se envíe por un socket UDP. Cada vez que llame a Malloc guardo la dirección del puntero en el array y después un for que lo recorra y valla ejecutando free para cada uno.

Comment: Esta bien esa idea, yo muchas veces he hecho eso.